# regular distributions

Tags: distribution-theory

I've somehow a really hard time showing that a distribution in $\mathcal{D'}(\mathbb{R^n})$ is regular.

The definition seems straight forward:

$ f \in \mathcal{D'}(\mathbb{R^n})  \text{ is regular if } \ \forall \varphi \in\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R^n}) \   \exists g\in {L}_{loc}^{1}(\mathbb{R^n}) \ s.t. f(\varphi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} g(x) \varphi(x) \ dx \\$ .

But I just don't see how one gets this function $g$.

For example one has given the function $f_n(x)= \frac{1}{n \pi} \frac{sin^2(x)}{x^2}$.

I mean I get the goal, it's now to find an integral such that $f_n(\varphi) = \int g_n(x) \varphi(x)$ dx.  But I just don't know how and where to start.

For the longest time I thought it is the same as to show that $f_n$ is locally integrable, but I was told it's (completely) wrong.

Comment: I would continue with your thoughts :-) A distribution $T$ is regular, iff there is a locally integrable function $g$ such that for all test functions $\varphi$ you have $T(\varphi)=\int g\varphi$. Do you see the difference in this statement compared to your "defintion" ?

Comment: Sorry, but I actually don't really understand the difference in both definitions.

Comment: Look for the order of the quantors ...

Comment: Oh, now I see the diffrence. Actually my "definition" was/is wrong in the first place. My bad. So I may choose any testfunction, for which I then need to find such a $g_n$?

Comment: No, you need to find a locally integrable funtions which fits for every test function. So you are perfectly right to show that $f_n$ is locally integrable, and whoever told you something different is wrong (in the context you mentioned).

Comment: I often show local integrablity by estimates, i.e. $ \int |f(x)| dx \leq K <\inf$ over some subset $G \in \mathbb{R}^n$ . But how do I proceed if the true value of $g$ is needed. $\\$ For the example above, it's not that hard to see that's integrable, since $|\frac{1}{x^2}|$ is bounded,$ |\sin^2(nx)|\leq 1$ over the interval $(0,\inf)$ for example, right? And for the case x=0  you are looking at the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R} \[-\epsilon,\epsilon] } |f(x)|$ and let  $\epsilon$ go to zero  (using dom. convergence)?

Comment: Yes, but the integral domain is $G\setminus [-\varepsilon,\varepsilon]$.